# "There is insufficient system memory in resource pool 'default' to run this query" error with MEMORY_OPTIMIZED tables

Tags: sql-server, memory-optimized-tables

I use Memory-Optimized Table in my SQL Server. However the error "There is insufficient system memory in resource pool 'default' to run this query" occures after several drop/create/insert operations with MEMORY_OPTIMIZED tables. For example I have created the memory_optimized table and I have loaded some data to the table. After that I have dropped the table, create the table the insert of the same data may be failed with the error "insufficient system memory".

Why may the error occured? Are there any ways how to avoid it?

The steps for reproducing the problem:

Run ms sql server in docker via command:

```
sudo docker run --memory=3g -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=Ab123456"    -p 1434:1434 --name sql1 --hostname sql1    -d    mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest
```

Create test database:

```
CREATE DATABASE my_db;

ALTER DATABASE my_db
ADD FILEGROUP my_db CONTAINS MEMORY_OPTIMIZED_DATA;
ALTER DATABASE my_db
ADD FILE (
    NAME=my_db_my_db, 
    FILENAME='/tmp/my_db_my_db'
) 
TO FILEGROUP my_db;

ALTER DATABASE my_db
    SET RECOVERY FULL;

BACKUP DATABASE my_db TO DISK = 'NUL';
```

Generate some data for testing:

```
CREATE TABLE test_data (
    id int NOT NULL identity(1,1), field varchar(max) NOT NULL
)
WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE);


declare @i int;
set @i =1;
while @i<=1000000 begin
    set @i=@i+1;
    INSERT INTO test_data (field) 
    VALUES ('asfd');
end;


Create memory_optimized tables:

CREATE TABLE my_memory_table (
    id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED HASH WITH (BUCKET_COUNT = 1500000), field varchar(max) NOT NULL
)
WITH (MEMORY_OPTIMIZED = ON, DURABILITY = SCHEMA_AND_DATA);


INSERT INTO my_memory_table (id,field) 
select top 1000000 id, field from test_data;


The next queries should be repeated several times before the error occures (in our case after 2 or 3 repeates):

DROP TABLE my_memory_table;

CREATE TABLE my_memory_table (
    id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED HASH WITH (BUCKET_COUNT = 1500000), field varchar(max) NOT NULL
)
WITH (MEMORY_OPTIMIZED = ON, DURABILITY = SCHEMA_AND_DATA);

INSERT INTO my_memory_table (id,field) 
select top 1000000 id, field from test_data;
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you're setting a governance on how much memory the hekaton tables can use, so it'll essentially use almost all of the memory for the instance. How much memory do these containers get?

Comment: The problem does't relate to the container's memory. The docker stats command shows 2 GB memory usage of 3 GB available and it doesn't become less after dropping the table. It seems that the memory is not completely cleared after deleting the table

Comment: It does and it doesn't. The more memory you have without a limit on hekaton, the more you can use before you'll get an error. What you're seeing is expected, you as the admin need to properly configure and admin the feature with the instance: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/estimate-memory-requirements-for-memory-optimized-tables?view=sql-server-ver16